# Is there an R function to add weekending Sunday by a given date

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I would like to mutate a week-ending Sunday to a dataset in R. For example [image]

This is what I have so far:

```
x <- seq(Sys.Date(), by = "1 day", length.out = 21)
data.frame(
  x = x,
  weekday = weekdays(x),
  next_friday = ceiling_date(x, "week") + 
    ifelse(weekdays(x) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), -7,0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps simpler:

```r
x + (7-as.integer(format(x, "%u")))
#  [1] "2021-04-11" "2021-04-18" "2021-04-18" "2021-04-18" "2021-04-18" "2021-04-18" "2021-04-18"
#  [8] "2021-04-18" "2021-04-25" "2021-04-25" "2021-04-25" "2021-04-25" "2021-04-25" "2021-04-25"
# [15] "2021-04-25" "2021-05-02" "2021-05-02" "2021-05-02" "2021-05-02" "2021-05-02" "2021-05-02"
```

Bigger:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  weekday = weekdays(x),
  next_sunday_date = x + (7-as.integer(format(x, "%u")))
)
transform(dat, next_sunday_weekday = weekdays(next_sunday_date))
#             x   weekday next_sunday_date next_sunday_weekday
# 1  2021-04-11    Sunday       2021-04-11              Sunday
# 2  2021-04-12    Monday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 3  2021-04-13   Tuesday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 4  2021-04-14 Wednesday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 5  2021-04-15  Thursday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 6  2021-04-16    Friday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 7  2021-04-17  Saturday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 8  2021-04-18    Sunday       2021-04-18              Sunday
# 9  2021-04-19    Monday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 10 2021-04-20   Tuesday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 11 2021-04-21 Wednesday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 12 2021-04-22  Thursday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 13 2021-04-23    Friday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 14 2021-04-24  Saturday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 15 2021-04-25    Sunday       2021-04-25              Sunday
# 16 2021-04-26    Monday       2021-05-02              Sunday
# 17 2021-04-27   Tuesday       2021-05-02              Sunday
# 18 2021-04-28 Wednesday       2021-05-02              Sunday
# 19 2021-04-29  Thursday       2021-05-02              Sunday
# 20 2021-04-30    Friday       2021-05-02              Sunday
# 21 2021-05-01  Saturday       2021-05-02              Sunday
```